# Graphical annotation software that hides small / huge text

Tags: maps, annotation

I have various graphics that I want to annotate with position markers and corresponding names or shorts texts. These information have varying scope: while some are describing small details, others are related to big parts of the graphic.

Take a map for example. If you look at a whole country, you don't want to see the name and location of every small city, but only a big text with the name of the country and small text for the biggest cities. When you zoom in, you want to see smaller cities and their markers, but probably want the country name to become smaller or vanish (because otherwise the huge text may cover whole cities).

I am currently using OneNote and Inkscape, which both work reasonably well so far, but don't seem to have any feature allowing this 'zoom-sensitive display'. Is there any application that can do this? I'm working on Windows, but would be interested in a *NIX solution too. I am using this for personal projects, so the software should be free or very reasonably priced (<100$).

Comment: OS? Price? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Are you actually dealing with spatial data / maps? Then a GIS application might be what you're looking for. So maybe you'll want to have a look at [QGIS](http://qgis.org/) (FOSS, cross-platform) and [scale dependent visibility](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/basic_map/symbology.html#moderate-fa-scale-based-visibility) for labels.

Comment: @LukasGraf That looks already pretty good. I'll take a look into it and let you know, thanks!